# Изменения ячейки по индексу в dataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Подскажите пожалуйста как кодом изменить значение ячейки например при нажатии кнопки

в WinForms

```
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[i].Value = "Текст";
```

Нужно примерно тоже самое но в WPF

Я добавляю в dataGrid свою строку Items с продуктом и мне нужно чтоб при следующем добавлении продукта с такимже id то количество увеличивалось

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или вот dataGrid при  нажатии на + увеличивалось значение ко-во на +1

Comment: Для `WPF` это не привычный подход, вам нужно использовать привязку данных и при нажатию на кнопку изменять элемент а затем оповещать интерфейс об изменениях

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void Add(Product product)
    {
        var r = CheckModels.Where(m => m.Product == product).ToList<CheckModel>();
        if (r.Count == 0)
            CheckModels.Add(new CheckModel { Count = 1, Product = product, Summa = product.Cost });
        else
        {
            var oldValue = r.First<CheckModel>();
            var count = oldValue.Count;
            CheckModels.Remove(oldValue);;
            checkModels.Add(new CheckModel { Count = count + 1, Product = product, Summa = product.Cost * (count + 1) });
        }
        SelectedItem = null;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо за улучшение кода