# Удалить строку из DataGrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Подскажите пожалуйста как удалить выделенную строку при нажатии Del
знаю только как определить выделение и как определить нажатие Del

```
private void dataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
        {
            // что за код надо написать
        }
    }
```

Comment: вы используете привязку данных для отображения в `DataGrid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы работаете без Binding и если имя у DataGrid dataGrid, то:

- **Узнаем индекс выделенной строки**

  `var index=dataGrid.SelectedIndex;`
- **Удаляем из строку с этим индексом из Items**

Все зависит от того как вы связывали DataGrid с данными.
Если без Binding, то можно просто методом **dataGrid.Items.RemoveAt(index);**

Comment: Я знаю как индекс найти! Как удалить его по индексу? какая команда удаляет строку по индексу ? Данные я не связывал они создаются в нем при работе (Add).

Comment: @JazMartin а можно взглянуть на код, как данные у вас создаются?

Comment: @JazMartin Можно удалить dataGrid.Items.Remove(index) Но так бы не советовал, лучше использовать Binding, а так как вы используете DataGrid, могу судить, что и будет вскоре бд или еще какая нибудь модель данных и тогда лучше использовать MVVM. Если нужно, то можно показать пример

Comment: Да я использую Binding при добавлении но как удалить я не знаю и по индексу не получилось `var datas = new Data { b0 = aD0.Text, b1 = "1", b2 = aD1.Text, b3 = aD1.Text, b4 = aD3.Text };
                        dataGrid.Items.Add(datas);`

Comment: @JazMartin Нет, здесь нет Binding. Вы напрямую, грубо говоря, пихаете данные в Items. Как вы добавляете данные, так и удаляйте - `dataGrid.Items.Remove(index);` Но вам нужно будет потом обновлять визуальную часть, ибо вы только удалите из Items, на визуальную часть это не распростроняется

Comment: @JazMartin ` dataGrid.Items.RemoveAt(index)` Этот метод удалит по индексу. Сейчас проверил, все работает `public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGrid.Items.Add(new Point(23, 25));
            dataGrid.Items.Add(new Point(234, 21));
            dataGrid.Items.Add(new Point(564, 54));
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            dataGrid.Items.RemoveAt(1);
        }`

Comment: `TextBlock aD0 = dataGrid1.Columns[0].GetCellContent(dataGrid1.CurrentItem) as TextBlock;
            TextBlock aD1 = dataGrid1.Columns[1].GetCellContent(dataGrid1.CurrentItem) as TextBlock;
            TextBlock aD3 = dataGrid1.Columns[3].GetCellContent(dataGrid1.CurrentItem) as TextBlock;`

Comment: @JazMartin и для чего вы скинули код выше? И судя по нему, вам лучше начать изучать Bindings и MVVM. Уж очень у вас мудреный код

Comment: Добавь пожалуйста в свой ответ `dataGrid.Items.RemoveAt(1);` чтоб кто ещё будет искать нашел ответ

Comment: @JazMartin Я давно уже этот вариант добавил, посмотри в конце)

Comment: Я не заметил... а как изменить значение можешь подсказать ? по индексу или Binding [Ссылка на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/693265/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%83-%D0%B2-datagrid-wpf)

Comment: @JazMartin опиши побольше задачу твою в том вопросе про изменение, ибо то что я увидел тебе будет все труднее и труднее реализовывать без привязок. Исходя из задачи постараюсь помочь

Comment: Я опишу на странице вопроса [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/693265/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%83-%D0%B2-datagrid-wpf)

Comment: @JazMartin увидел, да, тут явно лучше MVVM использовать. Сейчас напишу пример